# Can't get post-build event to run (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild, post-build-event

A project I have has a post-build event. That event seems to work fine for others, but it never happens for me. I put the compiler messages on diagnostic level, and got this:

```
Target "PostBuildEvent" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(PostBuildEvent)' != '' and ('$(RunPostBuildEvent)' != 'OnOutputUpdated' or '$(_AssemblyTimestampBeforeCompile)' != '$(_AssemblyTimestampAfterCompile)')) was evaluated as ('' != '' and ('' != 'OnOutputUpdated' or '' != '')).
```

So I know it's not the command inside that fails, bu the event is not even executed by VS. Even if I do a full clear/rebuild, deleting all the files in the output dir, no luck.

*Update:* The project file has this:

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
  ....
  <PostBuildEvent>
    <Command>xcopy /Q /Y /i filename $(OutDir)filename</Command>
  </PostBuildEvent>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
<ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
  <PostBuildEvent>
    <Command>xcopy /Q /Y /i filename $(OutDir)filename</Command>
  </PostBuildEvent>
....
```

Anyone know what could have gone wrong?

More information: VS 2017 (updated). The project in question uses v120, but this also happens for a clean v140 project.

*Update 2*: as suggested below, here are the logs collected by Collect.exe:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eV3VUAc9GgUa14b0qLND18J2ztj6o1q8/view?usp=sharing

*Update 3*: here is the result of `ag Error` (in bash) - it greps through a subdirectory recursively. I don't know if these errors are important and if so, what to do about them.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b7u_wvj7AaIHydmgWgkkLnxK-ySNfT1R/view?usp=sharing

Comment: How did you define postbuildevent in your project? Did you use this in vcxproj file:`<ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
<ClCompile>xxxxxxxx</ClCompile> <Link>xxxxx </Link><PostBuildEvent><Command>xxxx</Command> </PostBuildEvent></ItemDefinitionGroup>` Did you select the right configuration and platform to run the related postbuildevent? Besides, please try to create a new project to test whether the issue is related to your specific project itself or VS.

Comment: Happens in a clean ConsoleApplication project as well.

Comment: Quite very strange. first, please disable any third party extensions if you have under Extensions menu. Second, try to [repair VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019). Or run `devenv /safemode` on developer command prompt for VS to start vs and then test it to check whether third party vs packages cause it.

Comment: safe mode didn't solve the problem. Couldn't repair VS due to corrupted file so followed [1] to reinstall. Still the same issue.
[1] https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/97024/unable-to-repair-or-uninstall-vs-with-lastest-upda.html

Comment: Also, please make sure that you  use the related configuration and platform to build your project which executes the postbuildevent. And if it is not the problem, you can check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the further suggestions:

**Suggestion**

**1)** check if there is any OS updates, if so, you should update it to the latest version.

**2)** run cmd as administrator and then type these:

`DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth`

`DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:C:\RepairSource\Windows /LimitAccess`

`sfc /scannow`

More steps, you can refer to it: [use the System File Checker tool to repair missing or corrupted system files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929833/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system)

**In addition**, If the issue still persist, you can download [vscollect tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12493) and then [collect the build log](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/setup/visual-studio-and-net-log-collection-utility/), it exists under `%TEMP%vslogs.zip`. You can share it with us so that we can troubleshoot the issue more quickly.

Comment: Will try next week, I'm on a little vacation.

Comment: None of the above helped. I added a link to the vslogs.zip file in the OP. Thanks for any clue you can help me find.

Comment: No luck. And the system is fully up to date. 
Where did you find that error message? Maybe I can look in the same place and get some inspiration.

Comment: It seems that the Windows Installer error is in relation to Adobe Acrobat Reader, not related to VS. I can see a number of other "Error" occurences but I can't understand them.